# Perl isolating specific columns from file but doesnt work when there is special characters in one column

Tags: perl, multiple-columns, bioinformatics

I wrote a script to isolate specific columns from 1 file to a new file. It works as intended in most cases, however, when there is a / in one of the column from my data file, the following script will not work and only returns 1 line.

```
For example,
A B C D E
1 2 3 4 /sb/home/
1 3 4 5 /sb/home/

The script will only return 
1 2 3 +

Without the E column, it returns everything as intended.
1 2 3 +
1 3 4 +

use strict;
use warnings;

my ($file1, $file2) = @ARGV;

open my $fh1, '<', $file1;

open my $fh2, '>', $file2;

while (<$fh1>) {
    my @columns = split /\t/, $_;

    print {$fh2} "$columns[0]\t$columns[1]\t$columns[2]\t+\n";
}

close $fh1;
close $fh2 or die $!;
```

Any ideas as to why this is happening and ways to fix it?

Comment: Side note: unless you `use autodie;` at the top of your script, you should always check that calls to `open` succeed, e.g. `open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Failed to open '$file': $!";`

Comment: You are splitting on "\t" but your columns are separate by spaces or "\s".  Although... I suspect that is only part of the problem because when I use the same file format as you I get different output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are splitting on "\t" but your columns are separate by spaces or "\s"

Change

```
my @columns = split /\t/, $_;
```

to

```
my @columns = split /\s/, $_;
```

Also, Like David said check your line endings and make sure each line ends with a "new line" otherwise Perl may not process it correctly.

Comment: thanks for the tip i will try it out on the files that didnt work!

Answer (score 0):

I took your program, and changed it to this for testing:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
#
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($file1, $file2) = @ARGV;

while (<DATA>) {
    my @columns = split /\t/, $_;

    print "$columns[0]\t$columns[1]\t$columns[2]\t+\n";
} 

__DATA__
1   2   3   4   /sb/home/
1   3   4   5   /sb/home/
```

I get:

```
1   2   3   +
1   3   4   +
```

---

I suspect the issue is your input file. Perl reads to a NL, and if the file ends before a NL, you may not get that last line read. Check your file. Make sure the last line ends with a NL and see if that helps.

A few suggestions:

- Use `use autodie;` or check when you open a file. It's not that important to do so when you close a file.
- When you split, it's better to use `split /\s+/, $string;` because `/\s+/` means any number of spaces or tabs. If for some reason someone put two tabs in a row, or used spaces, it'll still work.